# Create a Folder based on first part of the file name

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I have a lot of files in a folder with this structure:

```
Client1.Date.1.log
Client1.Date.2.log
Client1.Date.3.log
Client2.Date.1.log
Client2.Date.2.log
Client2.Date.3.log
```

and so on.

I have more than 14,000 files.
I need to make a folder for each Client and move all the files into the correct Client Folder.
I'm on Ubuntu server 18.04 terminal.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is python script to move files from curent folder to client subfolders.

```
import os

# Finding files in given format in current directory
files = [fname for fname in os.listdir(".")
         if fname.count(".") == 3 and
            fname.endswith(".log")]

# Parsing client names
def client_name(fname):
    return fname.split(".")[0]

# move files to proper folders. Create folders if they don't exists
for fname in files:
    new_path = os.path.join(client_name(fname), fname)
    os.renames(fname, new_path)
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to tell not all the clients have the same format, my mistake, for example, i have file like this Rotson.010119.103010.log, Rotson.101019.103031.log, Burh.101019.103032.log Burh.101019.103033.log

the folder had to be the first part of the text, on this case, i need a folder called Burh and another called Rotson, the only common in all files is are the same format "client.date.order.log"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the longest trailing "dot suffix" of a string in variable `f` using shell parameter expansion `${f%%.*}`

So for example

```
for f in *.log; do mkdir -p "${f%%.*}" && mv --no-clobber -- "$f" "${f%%.*}"/; done
```

*I'd suggest making a backup copy of your data first, just in case it doesn't do what you expect*